# Koin: how to share class instances between scopes

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I'm trying to share an instance of a utility class between a parent activity and a child fragment's scope. Common sense would tell me that because the fragment is within the activity's scope I should be able to somehow access this utility. My module definition therefore would look like this:

```
internal val DemoModule = module {

    scope<DemoActivity> {

        scoped <DemoEncryptionHandler>{ DemoEncryptionHandler(androidContext()) }

        scope<DemoEncryptionFragment> {
            viewModel { DemoViewModel(get() /* shared instance of DemoEncryptionHandler */) }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this however I get the following error:

```
org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'com.sample.test.DemoEncryptionHandler'. Check your definitions!
```

So clearly it must be done differently. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You'll need to modify your scopes to provide name & then retrieve scope across other scopes using `getScope("your scope").get()`. This would provide you required dependencies across scopes.

Comment: The problem with that is then I lose the ability to call these dependencies from the lifecycleScope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this cannot be done. I also tried to add this functionality as an extension function but the way scopes are built and configured means it's a little harder than that. On the flip side it's possible to link scopes from Koin version "2.1.0 alpha". 
So what I did now is declare my module as above. Then I link my scopes in the fragment like so:

```
lifecycleScope.linkTo(requireActivity().lifecycleScope)
```

This seems to work just fine, although it's adding a dependency between the fragment and its host activity that I was hoping to eliminate by using Koin.